# meteor emit event then used by aframe eventlistener

Tags: meteor, aframe

I have an aframe object in main.html:

```
<a-gltf-model id='player1'  foobox playmyclip src="#myMixBun" ></a-gltf-model>
```

I want to have it perform a gltf clip animation when the eventListener ‘driveplay’ is emitted. 
In foofile.js:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('playmyclip', {
  init: function () {
    var el = this.el;
    el.addEventListener('driveplay', function () {
    el.setAttribute('animation-mixer', {clip: 'Drive', loop: 'once'});
    });
  }
});
```

Currently I have it so when the j key is hit ‘driveplay’ is emitted:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foobox', {
    init: function() {
    var el = this.el
    var swingno = 0;
     self = this;
          document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
          const keyName = event.key;
                if (keyName === 'j') {
                el.emit('driveplay',{},true);

                             // code to store record of event in Mongo for second player
                var playerid = self.el.getAttribute('id');
               var playerMid = Games.findOne({name: playerid})._id;
              Games.update({_id: playerMid},{$set:{swings : swingno}});
              swingno = swingno + 1;
             }
       })
   }
  });
```

But I also need to have the animation to happen at the same time on player2‘s screen. So in the above code I increment a variable in Mongo every time the animation happens. Then in main.js meteor automatically emits an event whenever “swingno” changes in Mongo.
main.js:

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'meteor/raix:eventemitter';
Event = new EventEmitter();
var swingcnt1 = 0;
Template.hello.helpers({
  counter() {
        if (Games.findOne())   //mongo is ready to access
      {
          var plyr1Swing = Games.findOne({name: "player1"}).swings;
        if (plyr1Swing !== swingcnt1) {
        Event.emit('driveplay',{},true);
    swingcnt1 = plyr1Swing;
        console.log(“this shows on player2’s console automatically”, swingcnt1);
   }
}
else    {null} 
return { ........};
},
```

When player1 hits the “j” key the animation happens correctly on his screen, plus the event is recorded in Mongo, and player2 receives the updated Mongo value (since it show in the console.log).

The problem is the

```
Event.emit('driveplay',{},true);
```

statement doesn’t trigger the animation in player2‘s screen. This is a little tricky, since I need meteor’s “raix:eventemitter” package to create an event that the aframe event listener can see.  It’s possible I’m not actually emitting an event at all, since I don’t know how to test if it’s working. Or possibly aframe can’t see the emitted event.

Possibly there’s an easier way of doing this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED  The solution  was to use the listener code from meteor’s raix:eventemitter package inside Aframe’s component.

﻿https://atmospherejs.com/raix/eventemitter

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('playmyclip', {
  init: function () 
      var el = this.el;
    listener = function() {
           el.setAttribute('animation-mixer', {clip: 'Drive', loop: 'once'});
   };
   Event.on('driveplay', listener);
 }
});
```

Plus the foobox component no longer needs:

```
 if (keyName === 'j') {
  el.emit('driveplay',{},true);
```

Both player1 and player2 get the animation event from

```
 Event.emit('driveplay',{},true);
```

in main.js when the meteor helper notices a change in the mongodb.